# Use a template-free tag to host a Recursive Component in Angular

Tags: angular, primeng, angular-template

I created an recursive component ***my-row*** in Angular, it means that it calls itself many times for each level of my tree data structure,

The template of the component ***my-row***:

```
<ng-container [pReorderableRow]="rowIndex" *ngIf="level === this.groupingLevels.length else child_row">
    <tr>
       <td [attr.rowspan]="rowGroupMetaData.indexes.length"> 
           {{rowGroupMetaData.source[col]}}
       </td>
    </tr>
</ng-container>


<ng-template #child_row>
  <my-row  *ngFor="let metaKey of getKeys(); index as i;"
          [rowGroupMetaData]="rowGroupMetaData.children[metaKey]"
  >
  </my-row>
</ng-template>
```

And I called it inside my table's body as follow:

```
<p-table
    [value]="[{}]"
    [columns]="cols"
    [reorderableColumns]="true"
    (onColReorder)="onColReorder($event)"
  >
    <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
      <tr>
        <th>
          {{col}}
        </th>
      </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowIndex="rowIndex" let-columns>
      <my-row *ngFor="let metaKey of getKeys(rowGroupMetadata)"
                  [rowGroupMetaData]="rowGroupMetadata[metaKey]"></my-row>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

The problem is that I must not put any tag between the tbody and it's tr otherway it will not appear, but I can use **ng-container** or **ng-template** between them because they don't affect the structure.

After discovering that I tried to host my component as a directive inside an **ng-container** / **ng-template**:

```
<ng-container my-row
                  *ngFor="let metaKey of getKeys(rowGroupMetadata)"
                  [rowGroupMetaData]="rowGroupMetadata[metaKey]"
></ng-container>
```

But unfortunately I have the error that says that **ng-container** is not used as host, neither **ng-template**.

Can you give some other potential components that I can use for hosting or another solution please.

Answer (score 0):

You could try following approach

Change in MyRowComponent the selector in the Component decorator so that it allows you to use components similar to directives

```
@Component({
  selector: '[my-row]', // instead of just 'my-row'
  templateUrl: './my-row.component.html',
})
```

In table's body make following change:

```
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowIndex="rowIndex" let-columns>
      // host my-row directly on a tr element
      <tr my-row *ngFor="let metaKey of getKeys(rowGroupMetadata)"
                  [rowGroupMetaData]="rowGroupMetadata[metaKey]"></tr>
</ng-template>
```

In the template of my-row

```
<ng-container [pReorderableRow]="rowIndex" *ngIf="level === this.groupingLevels.length else child_row">
   
   // if not child element, only show td as the host element is tr itself

   <td [attr.rowspan]="rowGroupMetaData.indexes.length"> 
       {{rowGroupMetaData.source[col]}}
   </td>
   
</ng-container>


<ng-template #child_row>
  <tr my-row  *ngFor="let metaKey of getKeys(); index as i;"
          [rowGroupMetaData]="rowGroupMetaData.children[metaKey]"
  >
  </tr my-row>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that I will have a  nested trs <tr> <tr> </tr> </tr> which is not correct

Comment: How does the structure you want to achieve look like exactly?

Comment: Like this: 
<table>
  <tbody>
     <tag>
       <tag>
         <tr>
         <td></td>
         </tr>
      </tag>
    </tag>
  </tbody>
</table
And I want that the tag will not appear in my template like <ng-container> and <ng-template> so that I will have the tr right under the tbody